# Is there a quick & easy solution to protect server 2012 against malware?

Tags: windows-server-2012, anti-virus, malware

For a Windows Server 2012 Standard GUI version to support a small IDE

Getting malware protection on my 1st server has become a much bigger problem than I imagined it would. My research covered a lot of pages, but the following 2 links stand out:

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831778 (last line of chart)
- http://blogs.technet.com/b/clientsecurity/archive/2012/11/05/more-information-on-microsoft-antimalware-protection-on-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx

I'm not wanting to start an opinion war so if this post is asked in the wrong forum or wrong way, just let me know.

But I need to install some kind of malware protection for my development environment and I can't figure out what to do. Since I'm not managing a large pool of servers or clients, it would seem Defender should be adequate until I am more experienced and understand what I'm getting into with larger malware detection management systems.

But I'm not even sure Defender can be installed and maintained on Server 2012 or how to do it, so if someone could give simple instructions to install Defender on Server 2012 assuming it is an acceptable/supported solution I'd appreciate it. My IDE servers aren't really exposed to attack all that much, but obviously I need some form of protection.

**Solution based on answer below:**

I wanted to follow up with a result for others new to servers as myself.  I created an SCCM install disk from the .iso file on my Microsoft subscription page and then found scepinstall.exe in the directory \smssetup\client.  I ran it from the CD and it installed 'System Center Endpoint Protection' which is effectively and therefore looks like Defender.  My big lesson, I was looking for the wrong name.  Again, big thx to Greg.  I'll start learning SCCM now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the Microsoft security product for Windows Servers, it is System Center EndPoint Protection (SCEP) 2012 R2, which is included with System Center Configuration Manager 2012 R2.  It is essentially 98% the same product as the consumer Windows Defender.   You should also download the CU4 update, which includes the latest build of SCEP (4.6.305.0) and Anti-malware updates.

February 2015 anti-malware platform update for Endpoint Protection clients
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3036437

You don't need to install SCCM.  If you only need the SCEP client, you can run scepinstall.exe.  The standalone configuration and update process is nearly identical to Windows Defender.

Comment: Finally got it! Thanks so much!  Your clarification cleared up my misunderstanding & also why I couldn't find Defender for Server 2012; it has a different name, SCEP.  I had seen a reference to scepinstall.exe but didn't know it was effectively Defender.  If I could ask, how do I download scepinstall.exe?  Do I get the whole SCCM & look for that file, or does the install ask if that's all I want, or is there a different process?  And yes, I wanted the Microsoft security product.

Comment: You may download the evaluation here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-system-center-2012-r2-configuration-manager-and-endpoint-protection

Comment: I notice it's an evaluation download.  Does using SCEP only incur a license fee?

Comment: Yes, I believe it does.

Answer (score 1):

There is a EMET software (The Enhanced Mitigation Experience Toolkit) who it's should be work for a preliminary line of defense without need of AV or Security suites in windows environment.

But, this is not a full protection. This is just a small wall so to speak.

Always best defense system are "Don't Click Anywhere" or get some firewall for internet connections.

Best regars

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Windows Security Essentials for Windows 7
2. Right click on mseinstall.exe and select Properties
3. Click the Compatibility tab
4. Check the Run this program in compatibility mode for: box
5. Select Windows 7 from the pull down menu
6. Click OK
7. Open a Command Prompt as Administrator
8. Navigate to the directory with mseinstall.exe
9. At the command prompt type "mseinstall.exe /disableoslimit" without quotes
10. Press enter and install normally

Comment: How are thee steps relevant? The OP is asking about Windows 2012?

Comment: Relevant because that is how to get it installed and running on 2012